# Android app cannot be installed providing a 505 error code

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

We recently upgraded our app Cachicha Videos Por Un Tubo v4.22, but some users not able to install app from Play Store. It says app cannot be installed providing a 505 error code. They can't even install an apk file directly on their phone.

It happens only to some users with late model Samsung phones including Samsung Galaxy 6. I can install app from Play Store successfully on my Google Nexus 6P(7.0) and other phones (S3 and S4).

I am guessing it was version compatibility issue.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/115166/851533/vxYKPcGwJy3qPPP/upload.png

Here are the configuration you can refer

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cachichasocial"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 27
    versionName "4.23"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[unknown installation error code -505](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/how-do-i-deal-with-unknown-installation-error-code-505)
Try this hope the solutions mentioned here helps you. 
Did you try increasing the target sdk?

Comment: yes, original build used target sdk 22, but got same issue. that' why I decrease it to 19